# Sound has disappeared on my account, works perfectly on Guest Session

Tags: unity, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So my sound has been working perfectly until I installed the Pulse Audio Equalizer, which was working for a bit, and then when I came back to my laptop, my Spotify app was giving me errors. I then realised I had no sound at all. I also cannot find any sound outputs in my Sound Settings which is a pain!

I've tried purging/removing/reinstalling pulse audio and force-reloading alsa and absolutely anything else I can find in these threads, but nothing seems to be working.

I logged into my Guest Session and sound was working perfectly there, though. There is the sound icon in the top left corner (whereas it only shows up as Mute if I try and show it in my account profile) and sound can actually be changed in my Guest Session.

Is there any way to get the same settings from my Guest Session as in my actual account? Sort of completely remove any tweaks I've made in this account?

EDIT:

After trying `pulseaudio --start --log level = 2` I received the output:

```
pulseaudio: option '--log' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--log-level' '--log-backtrace' '--log-time' '--log-meta' '--log-target'
```

`E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to parse command line.`

Comment: Try renaming your `~/.pulse` directory to something else (e. g. to `~/.pulse.bak`) and run `pulseaudio --start`. What's the output of the latter command? Do you have sounds now?

Comment: do I do that using mv? I tried that but I got the error: 'mv cannot stat '/home/*username*/.pulse':  No such file or directory'! @DavidFoerster

Comment: and when I try the 2nd command, I get 'E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.' I have a feeling my pulseaudio just isn't installing properly, even though I've done it exactly as I'm meant to do!

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Does your current user not have `.pulse` in his home directory? This shouldn't be a problem, though, because PulseAudio is supposed to create it in that case. Can you run `pulseaudio --start --log-level=2` and post the output, please?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have edited the question with the output I received!

Comment: Please copy & paste the command exactly as I wrote it! You forgot a dash in `--log-level` and added spurious spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me last year, sorry but I can't find the original source I found the fix from. But the solution was to do this:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse;
pulseaudio -k
```

Then logout and log back in. The first line removes the config folder for pulseaudio (which is I believe what @David Foerster was trying to have you do, maybe the folder is in different places in different versions of Ubuntu? I'm on 14.04), and the second command kills it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes, that works! As does your solution @DavidFoerster! However, for some reason it isn't saving when I restart my laptop. Everytime I reboot, the sound disappears and I'm having to put the commands in again. Is there a way to 'save' the edits I've made in the terminal so that it stays the same after a reboot? Thank you!

By the way, it happens with both the solutions - changes are gone after reboot with both solutions

Comment: Hmm, that's a bummer. Unfortunately that's the extent of my knowledge on this (which is obviously very little). Hopefully someone who knows more about pulseaudio can chime in, if not, we can work on filing a bug. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

Comment: @dannit I had installed nothing like Pulse Audio Equalizer though I had no  sound neither in my account nor in guest seesion.How can I solve this.

Comment: Restarted my laptop this morning and sound was gone yet the guest account had sound meaning it wasn't a hardware gone bad issue. Your solution worked though I renamed instead of deleting so that I can try and pin point the issue. PS: did not have to logout - in fact, as soon as I renamed the folder, the indicator changed out from muted state.